# Software error Perl while executing script

Tags: perl

Hi guys I have a problem

When I execute the Perl script, this is the error:

```
Software error:
CybOrg::Exception=HASH(0x1b65358)BEGIN failed--compilation aborted at CybOrg/DB.pm line 182.
Compilation failed in require at /var/www/cyborg/cyborg.pl line 30.
BEGIN failed--compilation aborted at /var/www/cyborg/cyborg.pl line 30.
```

Here is the [db.pm](http://pastebin.com/f5UbtxiJ)

Sorry for this newbie question. This is not my code.

Thanks in advance..

ADD

When I Run it into the browser

Internal Server Error

And when i Execute to terminal

```
    DB Error:db_connect
Params:HASH(0x1996098)

Status: 500
Content-type: text/html

<h1>Software error:</h1>
<pre>CybOrg::Exception=HASH(0x198d378)BEGIN failed--compilation aborted at CybOrg/DB.pm line 182.
Compilation failed in require at cyborg.pl line 30.
BEGIN failed--compilation aborted at cyborg.pl line 30.
</pre>
<p>
For help, please send mail to this site's webmaster, giving this error message
and the time and date of the error.

</p>
[Wed Mar 12 17:30:44 2014] cyborg.pl: CybOrg::Exception=HASH(0x198d378)BEGIN failed--compilation aborted at CybOrg/DB.pm line 182.
[Wed Mar 12 17:30:44 2014] cyborg.pl: Compilation failed in require at cyborg.pl line 30.
[Wed Mar 12 17:30:44 2014] cyborg.pl: BEGIN failed--compilation aborted at cyborg.pl line 30.
```

I don't know how to fixed it.
I hope somebody will help me..
Thanks in advance

Comment: It's not clear what you're asking here.  Please post a minimal example of code that reproduces the problem, don't use an external site (pastebin), and post the COMPLETE error message.  See [ask]

Comment: It's actually quite clear. He's getting an error, and he's asking what it means. He did provide he entire error message. This should not be closed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`_connect` is failing to connect to the database. The exact reason can be obtained with some changes to the CybOrb files.

1. Add the following to `CybOrg/Exception.pm` to cause something more meaningful than `CybOrg::Exception=HASH(0x1b65358)` to be emitted:

   ```
   use Data::Dumper qw( );

   use overload '""' => sub {
       my ($self) = @_;
       local $Data::Dumper::Useqq = 1;
       local $Data::Dumper::Terse = 1;
       local $Data::Dumper::Indent = 0;
       return
          "Error performing $self->{error_code} (" .
          Data::Dumper::Dumper($self->{error_params}) .
          ")";
   };
   ```
2. It's still not that meaningful because it turns out that the actual error message is never placed in the ::Exception object in this case. To get that, change lines 62-64 in `CybOrg/DB.pm` from

   ```
   _exception('db_connect', {'host' => "$database{'host'}",
                             'port' => "$database{'port'}",
                             'user' => "$database{'user'}"});
   ```

   to

   ```
   _exception('db_connect', {'error' => $@,
                             'host' => "$database{'host'}",
                             'port' => "$database{'port'}",
                             'user' => "$database{'user'}"});
   ```

Comment: Hi @ikegami
sorry for the late reply
but this is perfect I know the errors 
now
thank you very much....
thanks you..